# How do I create a new DB table for each CSV a user uploads in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

I am creating a Rails app where users will upload CSV files.  This part already works.

As each file is uploaded, I want to create a new table in the database for it (named something unique like csv_USERNAME_CSVID).
When it is created, an entry should be placed in another table 'csv_tables' that references each table that corresponds to a CSV.

What I want is the ability to do CRUD operations using Rails syntax like I do for everything else -- for example, Table.create(), Table.find(), and Table.destroy(), and likewise for each row of data within that table via method chaining.

How do I do this in Rails?

If this is not possible, would the next best option be to write a series of helper functions that perform the raw SQL queries needed to perform these manipulations?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the right way to go about this.

Rails assumes that model objects are going to be rows in a table, not an entire table. Working against this assumption will make your application very difficult to manage; you should probably restructure your model so that each individually uploaded CSV is a row in a table, not a table in and of itself.

Comment: This means I would lose the ability to sort, filter, and otherwise manipulate data in the CSVs, which is a large part of the purpose of the application.

Comment: I agree with Veraticus, even if you'd lose a lot of those abilities creating tables on the fly like that is not a good idea in my opinion. You could still perform those manipulations that you needed to, just perhaps not at a direct table level.

Comment: Can't you manipulate the data as a row? What transformations can you achieve with a table that you can't achieve as a row?

Comment: I don't see how a CSV--essentially a table of data--maps nicely onto a row.  For one, having arbitrary numbers of columns becomes problematic, as does adding new records to the "table-row".  Essentially, I lose everything I need from this part of the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a rake task for importing data from a csv file to your table.
But I would prefer a class method that does this job for me.

For reference to creating a rake task for SQL DB click [here](http://erikonrails.snowedin.net/?p=212)
For reference to creating a rake task for NOSQL DBS click [here](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2358583)

Here's an example for alternatively creating a class method (in case you don't want to create a rake task):

```
def self.populate_isd_codes
require 'csv'
csv_text = File.read("#{Rails.root}/data/import/phone/country_isd_codes.csv")
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true, :col_sep => ";")
csv.each do |row|
  row = row.to_hash.with_indifferent_access
  self.create!(row.to_hash.symbolize_keys)
  end
end
```

You can use this method from your rails console by typing table_name.method

Make sure that you create a table before importing data with the fields of same name as that of the header row of your csv file.